# Automatically create comment when file attached to jira issue

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Whenever an attachment is attached to an issue in Jira,I want to automatically create a comment.

The comment should be displaying the hyperlink to that attachment

Can anyone please help on how this can be done in Jira.

Thanks in Advance,
Naren.

Answer (score 0):

JIRA gives you the option to add a comment when you attach a file to an issue. It sounds like you want the comment to be required instead of optional? And to have a link to the attachment in the comment. My first thought is that this sounds like a new issue operation that extends the AttachFile action in a plugin.

Comment: Thanks!
But actually I want to monitor the file attach action for an issue and there is no **EventType.ISSUE_FILE_ATTACHED** for implementing the listener.

Whenever the file is attached, by detecting this action, I want to create a comment stating that the, "The 'current logged in user' has attached the file 'xyz.txt' " with a link to that attachment file